# I m trying to make a sliding underline with css but its not working for some reason

Tags: html, css, flexbox, underline

Its a sign in and login form I am trying to build which switches to sign up as soon as i hover on the button. I expect the underline to move as soon as hover on the sign up button. Please tell me why the underline isnt sliding.

```css
    #form{
        width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .butts{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    #form .butt{
        width: 150px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 25px;
        display: inline-block;
    
    }
    
    
    hr{
        height: .25rem;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 0;
        background: tomato;
        border: none;
        transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #butt2:hover ~ hr{
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <section id="form">
        <div class="butts">
            <button class="butt" id="butt1">Login</button>
            <button class="butt" id="butt2">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not works because, Css selector does not works for the higher node. "~" works only for adjacent element but here "hr" tag is adjacent to .butts class. Use below code to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

```css
    #form{
        width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .butts{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #form .butt{
        width: 150px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 25px;
        display: inline-block;
   }
    
    
    hr{
        height: .25rem;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 0;
        background: tomato;
        border: none;
        transition: 1s ease-in-out;
        position: absolute; 
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    
    #butt1:hover ~ hr{
        left: 0;
    }
    #butt2:hover ~ hr{
        left: 50%;
    }
```

```html
    <section id="form">
        <div class="butts">
            <button class="butt" id="butt1">Login</button>
            <button class="butt" id="butt2">Sign Up</button>
<hr/>
 
        </div>
               </section>
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir it worked!!! But please tell me why do we have to make the position of class butt relative to make it work...

Comment: Because i made "hr" position: absolute, absolute positioned element don't take real space but float on other element and calculates it's position offset (left, top, etc) from nearest relative positioned parent.